# Assign background-image as variable in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have got a **vue.js** component with a `div.icon`:

```
Vue.component('obj', {
  props: ['img', 'name'],
  template: '<div><div class="icon"></div> {{ name }}</div>'
})
```

While its easy to use `{{ name }}`, I do not know how to pass `{{ img }}`.

I have tried to add the following code, which does not work:

```
v-bind:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + {{ img }} + ')' }"
```

How can I use the props: `img` to assign a background-image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 'background-image' from [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2514):

```
v-bind:style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + img + ')' }"
```

Comment: This causes an error: > Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div style="{{ val }}">, use <div :style="val">.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but this does work neither. As the whole `template: ''` tag is wrapped inside the `' '` signs, the code creates a syntax error.

Comment: Escape them with `\'`

Comment: Thanks. Please add this important note to your answer for others to find it :)